# Firestore evergrowing collection

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm working on an app where users create certain events in a calendar.

I was thinking on structuring the calendar events data as follows:

```
allEventsEver/{yearId}/months/{monthId}/events/{eventId}
```

I understand that

> Firestore is optimized for storing large collections of small documents

but the structure above would mean that this would be an ever-growing collection. Is this something I should worry about? Would it be better to create a new collection for each year, e.g.:

```
2022/months/{monthId}/events/{eventId}
2023/months/{monthId}/events/{eventId}
```

Also, should I avoid using year/month value as document id (e.g. 2022) as those would be considered sequential ids that could cause hotspots that impact latency? If yes, what other approach do you suggest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most important/unique performance guarantee Firestore gives is that its query performance is independent of the number of documents in the collection. Query performance only depends on how much data you return, not on how much data needs to be considered.

So an ever-growing collection is not a concern on Firestore. As long put a limit on how many results your query can return, you'll have an upper bound on how much time it will take.